# checkbox / div toggle

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
  $(this).next(".toggle").slideToggle("fast");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  return false
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger">
<div class="toggle">content</div>
```

It isn't working, whats wrong with the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe put `<div style="display:none" class="toggle">` to hide it first? also, `return false` is unnecessary (and is missing a semicolon)

also, is this function within your `$(function() {});` ?

Comment: Ah, the problem was another plugin that was masking my checkbox with other elements. Fixed. Useful tips though, thanks